# Shell script EXECUTE CODE ON REMOTE SERVER AND get the result in local

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to check when the files have arrived on an remote unix server. I have made an script on my local server which puts filename and its date into an csv file but I need that file to be saved in my local server and not on remote server.

What should be the command like which let's me ssh to that server and execute rest of my code there and output the result in my local.

Comment: Please help us help you by letting us know which steps you already tried and how you were looking for the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you may try doing:

## ssh [username]@[servername] "command" >> /path/to/outfile.out

However, This command required password-less authentication between source and destination.

Comment: See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "...have already been asked and answered many times before". If you can identify some part of a question that hasn't been previously asked-and-answered that's different, of course, but everything in this answer here is already in the knowledge base many times over.

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup [key based authorization](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) and then just execute commands like that:

`ssh USER@HOST 'COMMAND'`

Or you can use `sshpass` to give a password directly in command line (not recommended!):

`sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh USER@HOST 'COMMAND'`